# Javascript Windows UI Automation

Tags: javascript, vb.net, ui-automation

In VB.NET, I can automate application installs using Windows UI Automation. Is it possible to do this in javascript? vbscript would also be acceptable but javascript is preferable.

Comment: You mean inside a browser?  I doubt it; Javascript in a browser is pretty well sandboxed.  You might try [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/).

Comment: TypeScript is no different than javascript

Comment: I can do the automation from Powershell and execute the powershell from an HTML page on a server?

Answer (score 1):

There a JavaScript tool to automation Windows UI application, LeanRunner Lite, can run with Node.js language. It can be installed from [Windows Store](https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9PDRR6ZL2PBQ)

Answer (score 1):

For Windows UI automation, try [`windows-app`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-app). For example, to use the calculator do this:

```js
const windowsApp = require("windows-app")
 
const {select, close} = await windowsApp("Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App") // Calculator app
 
await select.name_("One").click()
await select.name_("Plus").click()
await select.name_("Two").click()
await select.name_("Equals").click()
const result = Number((await select.accessibilityId("CalculatorResults").getText()).replace("Display is", ""))
 
console.log(`The result of 1 + 2 is ${result}`)
//=> "The result of 1 + 2 is 3"
 
await close()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using Appium. You may already know how to use Appium in Node.js/JavaScript.

Using NPM to download the Appium package, which is described here:

[Appium NPM Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/appium)

It already contains the Windows App Driver, which is described below:

https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/HEAD/docs/en/drivers/windows.md

Another alternative is to use the Win-App-Driver directly, as described below:
https://github.com/appium/appium-windows-driver

Answer (score -4):

JavaScript is limited to interaction with the DOM and remote servers (same origin policy plus exceptions if defined by the server), you can't install software on the client machine like that.